# How to search and return across multiple files?

Tags: python, search

Hi I was looking for some help and a starting point that would help me find a word or a phrase across multiple files so instead of CTRL + F and typing out the word to search in each individual file I could open all these files in python, run a search command, and it would give me the file names that return the key word.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is way too off-topic for this site. As a recommendation search on `os.walk` and `glob.glob`

Comment: You can also use a bach script, and with grep specify what you are looking for on each file. grep: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep

Comment: I usually do something like `grep -irl something .` to list all files that contains the string "something" (case insensitive) in the current directory and its subdirectories.

Comment: Or if you only want to search in text files, you could do something like this `find . -iname "*.txt" -exec grep -rl something {} \;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import os.path

for fname in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.isfile(fname):
        f = open(fname)
        if 'mystring' in f.read():
            print fname
        f.close()
```

You will need more than this if you need to search through subdirectories, but this will search every file in the current directory for an instance of `mystring`.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely make your own functionality as per your requirement in python if you want. I have not worked on python so far. I can give you general idea or logic to implement this functionality.

1. Take two arguments from users. First argument can be string or pattern of string for which you want search in multiple files. Second argument can be path to that folder in which you want to perform search.
2. Once you get path to that folder you can iterate through all files and folder to that path and can perform searching of that string in individual file.
3. simply save the instance of that file and location of file where you find your match in any data structure.
4. Once you are done with all files and folder just print out all results on console.

FYI: if you want such functionality for your own convenience then any operating system provides inbuilt functionality. Windows has [findstr](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true) and linux has grep function.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be something like...:

```
import fileinput

word = raw_input('Word to search for: ')

for line in fileinput.input():
    if word in line:
        print(fileinput.filename())
        fileinput.nextfile()
```

This is meant to be called with the files of interest on the command line -- so it's quite Unix-focused (as in Unix the shell will expand wildcards for you and the program receives the file names as arguments); in Windows you might have to do your own globbing.

In Python 3, change `raw_input` to `input`, but otherwise the code is the same.

It would be more elegant to pass the word to search for as the first argument, have some good default for what to do when called without file arguments, etc, etc, but all of these small complications will have to wait until you have clarified your exact requirements a lot better (what platform, what Python release, and so forth).